# Espresso / daggerMock: NullPointerException on Intents.release()

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, release, android-espresso

when I try to replace dependencies using [daggerMock](https://github.com/fabioCollini/DaggerMock), I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.internalRelease()' on a null object reference
at android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.release(Intents.java:140)
at android.support.test.espresso.intent.rule.IntentsTestRule.afterActivityFinished(IntentsTestRule.java:68)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:260)
```

This is my Espresso Intents rule:

```
@Rule public IntentsTestRule<MyActivity> activityRule =
        new IntentsTestRule<MyActivity>(MyActivity.class, true, false);
```

And this is my test

```
@Test
public void shouldDisplayToolbarOnStart() {
    startActivity();

    onView(withId(R.id.toolbar)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}

private MyActivity startActivity() {
    return activityRule.launchActivity(null);
}
```

My Espresso custom rule:

```
public class EspressoDaggerMockRule extends DaggerMockRule<RootComponent> {

    public EspressoDaggerMockRule() {
        super(RootComponent.class, new MainModule(getApp()));
        set(new DaggerMockRule.ComponentSetter<RootComponent>() {
            @Override public void setComponent(RootComponent component) {
                getApp().setComponent(component);
            }
        });
    }

    private static App getApp() {
        return (App) InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

*Temporary workaround*

Found a way to stop crashing:

```
@Rule public IntentsTestRule<MyActivity> activityRule =
        new IntentsTestRule<MyActivity>(MyActivity.class, true, false);
```

replaced by

```
@Rule public ActivityTestRule<MyActivity> activityRule =
        new ActivityTestRule<MyActivity>(MyActivity.class, true, false);
```

Comment: What is your question? What test state would you like to have? I don't understand your post, although I do understand that there were crashes and you cahnged the rule.

Comment: I just want my tests to run! I can't run any test with IntentsTestRule<MyActivity>

Comment: Try to remove `private MyActivity startActivity()` and remove `startActivity();` from your test method and then run the test. I don't feel that you need it